# Amazon AWS EC2 IP address won't display web page

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to build a t2.mirco Ubuntu 12.04 EC2 environment running Airtime from Sourcefabric, however despite the installation going through OK I cannot access the login page via the address that the installer provided. I have change my security settings several times but I feel that it might have something to do with it. I have ran system checks to see if airtime is working and it returns a perfectly operating copy every time. The address that i'm trying to access the installation on is http://ip-172-31-5-46.us-west-2.compute.internal does anyone know why Amazon AWS is reacting this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL you just provided is EC2's internal DNS address (note the ".internal" at the end), if you want it to be accessibly publicly you'll need to assign an Elastic IP to the EC2 instance, or auto assign a public DNS on creation of the instance

[Amazon docs for reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/GettingStartedGuide/EIP.html)

Comment: Thanks James. I have assigned an Elastic IP, and this seems to be the answer to the AWS part of the problem however still no luck actually fixing the Airtime part of the problem. Thanks